# What is difference between adding new values or synonyms to entities on IBM Watson Conversation?

Tags: ibm-watson, watson-conversation

I am using IBM Watson Conversation to build a chatbot. I am just wondering what is the difference between adding different synonyms to entity values rather than creating new values? Is it just a way to keep things organized?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value is the value of the entity, and the synonyms are the synonyms of that value.

For example, when you create one Entity `@devices`, and you add the Value `Samsung S7`, you can add the synonyms: `S7 by Samsung`, `S7 Samsung`, etc.

And when you access the entity value like: `@devices`, you'll get the real VALUE name (`Samsung S7`), and not the synonyms.

But you can access the synonyms value with the `.literal` property to get the exact text that was recognized as the detected entity, for example:

`<?@devices.literal?>`

One good idea to use the synonyms is if you want one specific value from the user and the user *types with different forms*. For example, I did one entity with `@Positions`, and I added a lot of values like:

- **Value**: Support Analyst **Synonyms**: Support Technican
- **Value**: Windows Analyst **Synonyms**: Support Analyst, Windows Support, etc
- **Value**: Linux Analyst **Synonyms**: Support Linux

Because, in my case, I want to save the real value from my entity.
I wanna save: Support Analyst, Windows Analyst and Linux Analyst, because they are the real value from the `@positions` in my Company.

If the user types Support Technican, the entity `@positions` will be detected and the value `Support Analyst` will be available inside the `@Positions` entity, for example.

Reference: Watson Converstation Service Documentation [here](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/conversation/expression-language.html#accessing-and-evaluating-objects).